# How can I create a scroll list that has not always the same amount of rows?

Tags: c#, xna

My scroll list has not always the same amount of rows and I want to disable scrolling down when the last row is completely visible at the bottom of the scroll list.

But right now, it is still possible to scroll down if the last row(in this case row 13) is completely visible at the bottom of the list. Then it looks like the third image(After more scrolling), but I want that it looks like the second image(After scrolling).

What can I do so that you cannot continue scrolling down after the last row is completely visible?

**UPDATE: It works now. This code version uses variable scrolling speed.**

[image: scroll list pictures]

My code:

```
//Creating the scroll list: 

public List<Vector2> ScrolllistInitialRowPosYList = new List<Vector2>();
public List<Vector2> ScrolllistRowPosYList = new List<Vector2>();
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle ScrollPointRectangle, tappRect, ScrollRectangle;
int ScrollLimitTopPosY = 200, ScrollLimitBottomPosY = 400, RowHeight = 60, ScrollPointStartPosY;
float ScrollAreaHeight, HeightallRows, ScrollSpeed;

ScrollPointStartPosY = ScrollLimitTopPosY;
ScrollPointRectangle = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(500, ScrollPointStartPosY, ScrollPointSprite.Width, ScrollPointprite.Height);
tappRect = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(-150, -100, 10, 10);
ScrollRectangle = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(500, 300, ScrollRectangleSprite.Width, ScrollRectangleSprite.Height);

int FirstRowPosY = 0;
int NumberofRows = 13;
ScrollAreaHeight = ScrollLimitBottomPosY - ScrollLimitTopPosY;
int ListViewportHeight = 6 * RowHeight;
HeightallRows = NumberofRows * RowHeight - ListViewportHeight;

ScrollSpeed = HeightallRows / ScrollAreaHeight;

for (int i = 0; i <= NumberofRows - 1; i++)
{
     ScrolllistInitialRowPosYList.Add(new Vector2(500, FirstRowPosY));
     ScrolllistRowPosYList.Add(new Vector2(500, FirstRowPosY));                     
     FirstRowPosY += RowHeight;
}

//Updating gestures:

                    case GestureType.FreeDrag:
                    if (tappRect.Intersects(ScrollRectangle))
                    {
                        tappRect = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle((int)gs.Position.X, (int)gs.Position.Y, 10, 10);

                            if (gs.Delta.Y > 0)
                            {
                             if (ScrollPointRectangle.Y >= ScrollLimitTopPosY + 2)
                                ScrollPointRectangle = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(500, ScrollPointRectangle.Y - 2, ScrollPointSprite.Width, ScrollPointSprite.Height);
                          else
                                ScrollPointRectangle = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(500, ScrollLimitTopPosY, ScrollPointSprite.Width, ScrollPointSprite.Height);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (gs.Delta.Y < 0)
                                {
                                    if (ScrollPointRectangle.Y <= ScrollLimitBottomPosY - 2)
                                      ScrollPointRectangle = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(500, ScrollPointRectangle.Y + 2, ScrollPointSprite.Width, ScrollPointSprite.Height);
                                    else
                                      ScrollPointRectangle = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(500, ScrollLimitBottomPosY, ScrollPointSprite.Width, ScrollPointSprite.Height);
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    break;

//Updating the scroll list after someone srolled up or down:

        for (int i = 0; i <= ScrolllistRowPosYList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int ScrollPosYCurrent = ScrollPointRectangle.Y;

            int ScrollPosYDifference = ScrollPosYCurrent - ScrollPointStartPosY;
            float RowPosYDifference = ScrollSpeed * ScrollPosYDifference;

            int RowInitialPosY = (int)ScrolllistInitialRowPosYList[i].Y;

            float RowCurrentPosY = RowInitialPosY - RowPosYDifference;

            ScrolllistRowPosYList[i] = new Vector2(ScrolllistRowPosYList[i].X, RowCurrentPosY);
        }
```

Comment: You can calculate the total height required to display all the rows, then subtract the your listbox's *viewport* height.  The result of that calculation is the max value of a scrollbar that ranges from 0 to <height> that can be used to clamp the items so that the list item cannot scroll past the bottom of the scrollable area.

Comment: Thanx @Bradley Uffner. It works now. I updated my code. I added ListViewportHeight and I changed some int variables to float variables.

Comment: I still have a problem with the scrolling speed, scrolling is too slow when I just have a few rows, for example 15. On the other hand, scrolling is too fast when I have many rows, for example 200. How can I adjust the scrolling speed so that it's not too slow or too fast in one special case?

Comment: Instead of making the scrolling speed dependent on the ratio of items to height, I would consider just making it scroll at a constant speed.  Just figure out what a comfortable number of pixels per second is, and divide that number by your framerate, then scroll by that number of pixels each frame that you want to scroll.  That's the basic way scrollable controls work in Windows.  I would follow that familiar model.

Comment: Thanx. Scrolling at constant speed solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could just not draw them.
2. You could have 2 `List<row>` variables, where one would store all rows, and the other only the ones that should be viewed and interacted with.

**EDIT**: I missread. Forget the first point I wrote.
Use two lists like in 2nd point. When scrolling, check if the last visible row is the last row in your "all rows" list. If so, don't scroll.